# Paying taxes as a Kansan moving to Paraguay

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, international, paraguay

I know these situations get mentioned a lot but I'm looking for documentation for this scenario.

I'm a US Citizen that's lived in Kansas for several years now and I'm looking to move to Paraguay for a couple years starting July. I've got a visa to live there so that's not a problem. I know I'll have to file federal taxes as usual and part of state taxes for the time I lived here. My employer wants to make sure there aren't any issues paying me the way they've been paying me normally for years to my American bank while I'm down there. My questions are:

1. Do they have to report my physical address to the IRS or use my mailing address (parents house that live in the US) or neither?
2. From what I understand, I don't pay Paraguayan taxes because I'm not working for a Paraguayan company and don't get paid to a Paraguayan bank. Is this something my employer should worry about? By worry I mean how can they be sure they're paying me legally while I'm living there.

The main concern is they want to make sure they can keep paying me like they've been paying me (withholding federal and state taxes) without getting in trouble with Paraguayan tax laws.

Thanks in advance!